# Durandal View composition: How to update a inner html page instantly when other inner html page sends data?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal-2.0

I'm using DurandalJs 2.0 and KnockoutJs. I have two HTML pages, **add.html** and **show.html** with their JS files. I want to display both pages as **composition** in one **index.html** page. On the left is show.html and displays added records, on the right is add.html which allows users to add records.

My problem is that; show.html page should **instantly** show or append the record as the user adds a new record. When I add a record, it is updated in the repository.js, but how to refresh only show.html to read new record. I tried router.navigate("#/client/index") but it did not work.

```
<div>
<div id="global">
    <!-- ko compose: {model: 'viewmodels/client/show', view:'views/client/show'} -->
    <!-- /ko-->
    <div id="main" class="container">

        <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
    afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
    transition: 'entrance'} -->
        <!-- /ko-->

    </div>
    <div id="push">
        <!-- ko compose: {model: 'viewmodels/client/add', view:'views/client/add'} -->
        <!-- /ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use application messaging for this. Durandal provides a publisher/subscriber mechanism to communicate between diferent modules whithin the application.

To use this feature, you need the application module from Durandal in both viewmodels:

```
 var app = require('durandal/app');
```

In the `add` viewmodel you can add the code to send a message with the new client to the subscribers, in this scenario the `show` viewmodel:

```
addClient: function(client){
    app.trigger('client:add', client);
}
```

The string `'client:add'` is the identifier of the event and  the following argument is the message  to send  to the subscribers. In your scenario, you want to send the new client.

Your `show` viewmodel could have the following code in the `activate` method:

```
activate: function(){
    var self = this;
    subscription = app.on('client:add').then(function (client) {
        self.clients.push(client); //add client into a ko.observableArray?
    };
}
```

The `on` method needs  the identifier of the event and returns a promise that can be used to execute  the code when the event is triggered. Please note that the method returns a subscription object that we can use in the future to cancel the subscription.

Maybe when this view is deatached of the UI you need to cancel the subscription:

```
 subscription.off();
```

You could also use other approaches like sharing the same instance of an `observableArray` between the viewmodels, for example. However I think application messaging is a good way to communicate and decouple parts of the application.

Comment: Thanks margabit, It worked! But, it gets added twice to the list. For the second Id is null, but rest data is same as the first.

Comment: Maybe your activate is being called twice? Or you are not calling `subscription.off()` in the right place?